# Submitting document to server and the formData seems to be blank

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, dropzone.js, react-dropzone

Been struggling with this issue for a while now and really need to get it resolved.

I'm using `react-dropzone` to setup file upload in a React-Redux application. It seems to be working, as it says it has successfully sent to the server, but what is received by the server (`Django REST Framework`) appears to be an empty `MultiValueDict`. However, the request payload has the following:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryWiq9rPvu5bpEoR4X
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

[object File]
------WebKitFormBoundaryWiq9rPvu5bpEoR4X--
```

So maybe the front-end is fine, but something is going on server-side. Trying to isolate where exactly the problem is occurring. I just know the `console.log(formData)` doesn't seem to indicate a file is appended there.

Anyway, here is my code:

```
// ./containers/documents/submit_documents.js
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { submitDocument } from '../../actions/documents';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';

class SubmitDocuments extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            files: []
        }

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onDrop = this.onDrop.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        this.setState({
            files: []
        });

    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.submitDocument(this.state.files);
    }

    onDrop(files) {
        // console.log(files);
        // files.push(this.state.files);
        this.setState({
            files
        });
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className='panel panel-default'>
                    <div className='panel-heading'>
                        <h4><strong>Submit Documents</strong></h4>
                    </div>

                    <div className='panel-body'>
                        <Dropzone className='dropzone' onDrop={this.onDrop}> 
                            <h3>Click to add files or drag files here to upload</h3>
                        </Dropzone>
                        <div>
                            {_.map(this.state.files, f =>
                                <h5 key={f.name}>{f.name} - {f.size} bytes</h5>
                            )}
                        </div>
                        <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
                        <button type='button' className='btn btn-danger' onClick={this.handleClick}>Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        ); 
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        documents: state.home.documents
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { submitDocument })(SubmitDocuments);
```

And the associated action file:

```
// ../actions/documents.js
import axios from 'axios';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
import { ROOT_URL } from '../../config/config.json';

// Establish the different types
export const DOCUMENTS = 'documents';

// Creates the error state to be used in components
export function submitDocument(files) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', files);
    console.log(formData);
    return function(dispatch) {
        axios
            .post(
                `${ROOT_URL}/api/documents/fileupload`,
                formData,
                { headers: 
                    { 
                        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
                        'Authorization': 'JWT ' +  sessionStorage.getItem('token')
                    }
                }
            )
            .then(response => {
                console.log('Success')
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Failed');
            });
    }
}
```

It seems like the server is expecting a key value pair with `file`, which seems like it should be getting created with the `formData.append('file', files);` but not seeing anything like that in there.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try to iterate the `files` and for each `formData.append(file.name, file.data)`.

Comment: Yep, that got it working. If you want to submit your response I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate `files` and for each `formData.append(file.name, file.data)`.

The `onDrop` method, provides you with an array of [Files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) which you can then send to a server.

[How to upload files using `FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects).